# angular, how to stop tracking on service objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I have a service where I store all my DTOs classes i map back to api calls. 
When I use those service objects they are getting tracking all the way back to the service, so i cant renew them if i want to make another transaction.

here is the service

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("app.bms");

    app.service("dtoObjects", function () {

        var state = {
            Id: "",
            Value: ""
        }

        var companyDto = {
            Id: "",
            Name: "",
            Address: "",
            Address2: "",
            City: "",
            State: state,
            Zip: "",
            Phone: "",
            contactName: ""
        }

        var departmentDto = {
            DepartmentID: "",
            DepartmentName: "",
            CompanyDto: companyDto,
            IsActive: false,
            States: [state]
        }

        var userDto = {
            UserId: "",
            FistName: "",
            LastName: "",
            Email: "",
            Phone: "",
            LoginName: "",
            Password: "",
            IsActive: "",
            Client: companyDto,
            Department: departmentDto
        }

        return {
            departmentDto: departmentDto,
            companyDto: companyDto,
            userDto: userDto
        }

    });
})();
```

Here is how I inject it.

```
function userInfoController($scope, userService, dtoObjects, ngTableParams, popUpService, modalService)
```

This is How I use it

```
var userDto = dtoObjects.userDto;
            popUpService.raisePopUp(addEditTplt, addEditCtrl, userDto, reloadTable);

            console.log(dtoObjects.userDto)
```

;

everything that i assigned to that object is now mapped it back to service. 
Is it possible for angular to stop this deep watch on service?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to have DTO return a constructor function and `new` it whenever you need a new transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the DTO service in a function and use new to instantiate a new copy every time you need to reset. So your service would look like this:

```
(function() {
"use strict";
var app = angular.module("app.bms");
app.service("dtoObjects", function() {
    function dto() {
        return {
            companyDto: companyDto
            //...
        }
        var companyDto = {
            //...
        }
    }
    return dto;
});})();
```

And then you would use it like so:

```
var newDTO = new dtoObjects();
console.log(newDTO.companyDTO);
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, part of the power of Angular is the fact that services are singletons, and therefore a single reference can be bound everywhere in your app.  Using DTOs in Angular tend to add large amounts of unnecessary complexity, since Angular shouldn't be concerned about transaction states on the server.

However, if you absolutely need this feature, you can use [`angular.copy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy#!) to make a copy of your DTO for use in your view.

```
//example with 1 argument
var userDto = angular.copy(dtoObjects.userDto);

//example update, using two arguments
angular.copy(userDto, dtoObjects.userDto);
```

Comment: Thank you, i completely forgot about copy.
Only reason i start doing this is because we have fairly complex model and i though keeping them in sync like this will avoid confusion.